# What is the word for students under the same advisor

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, nouns, synonyms

I'd like to know what is the word to describe students under the same advisor in graduate program, e.g. PhD program. Normally, students in the same department who attend the same classes are called *classmate*.

But I can not find a word for students under the same advisor in English. However, this exists in some languages. For example, in Chinese, it is known as 师兄弟 or 师姐妹.

Comment: In my university in the UK we refer to each other as 'fellow students  of Professor X'.

Comment: Advisees will do.

Comment: (US English) I'm meeting another student in my group at 4 this afternoon.  Professor: I'd like you to work on this project with another student in the group, of your choice.  Aunt Dee, I'd like to introduce my groupmate, Alex.  Hey, guys, this is Alex, who just joined Professor Ming's group.  *(The other students are in the same department and they know who Prof. Ming is, but they are working in other groups.)*  HOWEVER, if it's an experimental science, then it's common to use "lab": Alex is working in Professor Ming's lab.  Etc.

Comment: Ok, I think 'groupmate' is close to what I want, but still not accurate because it does not include those who has graduated and left the group.

Comment: I don't think there's a common word for this, because students who happen to have the same advisor don't generally do anything together that requires naming them as a group.

Comment: Even if they donot form a group, it still needs a name sometimes. Some languages like Chinese do have such words.

Comment: I think *fellow student* will do in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on a single word, *condisciple* means fellow student of the same teacher.

- [*condisciple*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/condisciple) noun (plural *condisciples*) con·​disciple | kän + disciple

  1. a fellow disciple or student; schoolfellow

*Disciple* is taken in the sense of a follower or pupil of the same teacher, leader, or philosopher.
The word is current in modern French but relatively rare in English

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I believe that I find the one in this case: *fellow student*.

Comment: *Fellow student* is good.  Also *labmat* is common in some fields.  Maybe also *groupmate*.

Comment: "Fellow student" could mean those on the same course or at the same school rather than with the same advisor.